# Fancybox on mobile device failed to scale the external page?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile, fancybox

Fancybox on mobile device failed to scale the extrnal page?

I'm using fancybox on a site. When user on the page, fancybox pops and show an external url. This external url is a responsive page, by itself, it works fine on both normal PC and mobile device. It show a youtube video and a form.

However, when using fancybox to show this page, it works fine on regular PC (if the browser window is not too small). But on mobile device, the youtube video and form size will not scale automatically, so only part of the page shown on the mobile device.

[image]

Is there a setting that I should change in fancybox? or, this is the limitation of fancybox? any other similar plugin/javascript library can do the similar things on both mobile and regular pc?

Here is the code:

```
$('#IntroVideo').fancybox({     
    'autoDimensions': false,
    'padding': 0,
    'width': '100%',
    'height': '100%',
    'autoScale': true,
    'autoSize': true,
    'transitionIn': 'none',
    'transitionOut': 'none',
    'type': 'iframe'
});

...

<div class="searchtag-wrap ">
    <a href="https://www.example.net/" class="frontpage-button" id="IntroVideo">What is MySite?</a>
</div>
```

**Or, is it possible to disable fancybox on mobile device? how?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fancy 3 seems to be working perfectly, which version of fancybox you are using?

Here is a working example, tested it on android phone running android 6.

```css
.fancybox-slide--iframe .fancybox-content {
 width  : 800px;
 height : 600px;
 max-width  : 95%;
 max-height : 90%;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Fancybox</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.css" /> 
</head>
<body>
<a data-fancybox data-src="https://www.awwwards.com/" href="javascript:;">
 Webpage
</a> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JSbin of the above code https://jsbin.com/noxoke/edit?output

Comment: no, it still the same issue. the external page is https://www.  myzipmail.  net /mzm , maybe the page has some issues? or, is it possible to disable fancybox when it is on mobile device?

Comment: couldn't open the website you provided, yes you can disable fancybox on mobile devices, please check javascript code to disable here https://jsbin.com/noxoke/edit?html,js,output